# How to make uniq data in Clickhouse use DISTINCT in condition HAVING?

Tags: clickhouse

I need to filters data in Clickhouse use uniq table l.views, l.contacts.
First idea, ofcose, change condition parser and delet doubles.
How it make better?

```
WITH prepare_price AS (SELECT price FROM log
                    WHERE category_uuid = '2504aa40-773e-5343-8772-2c7e0244a912'
                    AND created_at between '2023-10-01' and '2023-12-01'
                    GROUP BY price
                    order by price
                    LIMIT 8192)
SELECT
    cat.uuid,
    cat.name,

    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s.uuid) FROM seller s
                                LEFT JOIN log l on l.seller_uuid = s.uuid
                            WHERE l.category_uuid = '2504aa40-773e-5343-8772-2c7e0244a912') as seller_count,

    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT b.uuid) FROM brand b
                            LEFT JOIN log l on l.brand_uuid = b.uuid
                        WHERE l.category_uuid = '2504aa40-773e-5343-8772-2c7e0244a912') as brand_count, 

    sum(l.gmv) as revenue, 
    count(l.product_id) as p_count, 
    sum(l.item_rating_reviews_count) as item_rating_sum, 
    sum(l.views) as p_views, 
    sum(l.contacts) as p_contact, 

    round(revenue / seller_count) as rev_dev_sellers, 
    round(p_views / seller_count) as view_dev_sellers,
    round(p_contact / seller_count) as cont_dev_sellers, 
    round(p_contact / p_views * 100, 2) as cv, 

    round(revenue / p_count) as rev_dev_product, 
    round(p_views / p_count) as views_div_product, 
    round(p_contact / p_count) as contacts_div_product, 
    round( contacts_div_product / views_div_product * 100, 2) as cv_product,

    round(revenue / brand_count) as rev_dev_brand, 
    round(p_views / brand_count) as views_div_brand, 
    round(p_contact / brand_count) as contacts_div_brand, 
    round(contacts_div_brand/ views_div_brand  * 100, 2) as cv_brand, 

    round(avg(l.item_rating_float), 2) as avg_product, 
    min(l.price) AS min_price, 
    max(l.price) as max_price, 
    round(avg(l.price), 2) AS avg_price, 
    (SELECT medianDeterministic(price, 1703172320) FROM prepare_price) as median 
from log l
    left join category_product cp on cp.product_id = l.product_id
    left join category cat on cat.uuid = cp.category_uuid
where cat.uuid = '269a60be-9c45-5e4a-b4c8-931de0f9b67b' and l.product_id = '2749912816'
group by cat.uuid, cat.name
```

It's example SQL query. All date million rows.

How do it better or example query.